# How to remove app suggestions on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge, Android 8.0?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge on Android 8.0. I want to remove app suggestions on the search bar.

I already checked for some solutions on YouTube. Everyone tells me to go to Home Screen settings and then go to suggestions, but there are no options named suggestions.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by app suggestions. When I had an S7, I  didnt get any. There are ads from apps and perhaps your service provider.

Comment: Samsung has several versions of [UI customization](https://r2.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-J/SAMSUNG-ANDROID-FROM-TOUCH-WIZ-TO-ONE-UI/td-p/1359266), from TouchWiz to Samsung Experience and lastly One UI. Have you checked the method specifically for your device model and Android version?